# Why is my calculation of this inner product incorrect?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Let {$x_n: n=1,2,3,...$} be a linearly independent set of vectors in $H$. Put $v_n = x_n - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \langle x_n, u_i\rangle u_i$, $u_n =v_n / ||v_n||$.

I need to show {$u_n$} is an orthonormal set.

My attempt: of course $||u_n||=1$ for all $n$. So we only need to show $\langle u_n,u_m \rangle =0$. Since $u_n$ and $v_n$ differ only by scalars, it is enough to show that $\langle v_n,u_m \rangle=0$.

Then my calculation becomes:

$$\langle v_n,u_m \rangle = \langle x_n -\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\langle x_n, u_i \rangle u_i, u_m \rangle$$

$$= \langle x_n, u_m \rangle -\langle\langle x_n, u_1\rangle u_1, u_m\rangle - ... - \langle\langle x_n, u_{n-1}\rangle u_{n-1}, u_m\rangle $$

$$=\langle x_n, u_m\rangle - \langle x_n, u_1\rangle \langle u_1, u_m\rangle -... - \langle x_n, u_{n-1}\rangle \langle u_{n-1}, u_m\rangle$$

$$=\langle x_n, u_m\rangle$$

But it's wrong. It should be 0. Where did I get wrong?

Comment: Use induction on the number of elements of your set of vectors.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You seem to have assumed that $\langle \langle x_n,u_i\rangle u_i,u_m\rangle$ will be zero for all $i$, but what happens if $i=m$?